# Best MySQL type for very long CSV data

Tags: mysql

What would be the best MySQL type to use to store very long CSV data?  say half a million integers of 5 digits or less?

Also, what would be the benefit/drawback of adding a new column to the table instead of adding a new value to the CSV string?  Can a MySQL table even have half a million columns?

I would be updating the table either way, one 5 digit integer at a time, and I would need to search through either the CSV string or the columns a lot?

Basically what I'm doing is recording which of my users have voted for a certain idea so no one can vote more than once.  There is not a set number of ideas however, it is constantly expanding, and I dont want to add anything to my already fairly big Users table.

Would it be better to create a new table for each idea that will be voted on?

What would be the fastest/least processing intensive route here?

Comment: I have answered your question, but it is apparent you don't know the basic concepts behind using relational databases. Both of your proposed solutions (many values in a single column as a CSV, or one column for each user-idea pair) show ignorance of how to store data and its relationships in a database. You need to pick out a good book on database design and read it. The very first chapter or two should set you straight.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between users and ideas they've voted on should be represented by a table with a column identifying the user and a column identifying the idea. When a user votes on an idea, you insert a row into this table. The column pair is the primary key of this table, which enforces uniqueness (preventing duplicate votes).

Comment: I'm going to have an Ideas table, with info such as: short description of idea, who contributed the idea, a timestamp for when the idea was submitted, etc.  Also an Idea Serial number set up with auto increment, this will be the main identifier of the idea and primary key.  So how best to use the Idea table and the Idea Votes table together?

Comment: I already described how best to model the relationship between ideas and users (aka votes) in the answer you're replying to. Your "idea serial number" is the foreign key which will be in this 3rd table, along with the user's identifier, to form the (user, idea) pair representing a vote by a user on an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding all votes for a user in one row, make one row per vote and user. The table then contain of two columns 1. the user and 2. the idea the user voted for. This solves your problem and also enables you to do more things easier in the future; eg. count number of votes for a certain idea.